# c++ testing herimitic library

Tags: c++, testing, libraries

I decided to add tests for my library.
The problem is that most (all?) of the test frameworks are using the same approach: build an executable file which contains code to be tested, tests and framework.

But what if I have a library which is heavy (a lot of code inside) but has only a few public functions / classes? In such situation I cannot test it well until:

1. I export all symbols from library
2. I build executable file with all library sources included

Ad. 1: it's not nice

Ad. 2: when I work with visual studio it would require me to synchronize library project with 'test' executrable project (adding/removing files etc). So it also doesn't look nice for me.

Are there any other approaches?

Comment: What's *hermetic* supposed to mean in your context?

Comment: I knew it will be a bad word ;) I just mean there is a lot of code (to be tested) which is hidden in library and there are only a few public interfaces.

Comment: It's funny how many times you see words like that being used figuratively as adjectives.

Comment: Use adjectives literally, it makes your text clearer! I spent 5 minutes wondering if you meant *herimitic* instead :)

Comment: Have you considered maybe refactoring this library? You could benefit from redesigning this library in a way that you have many smaller libraries with clear apis that can be tested separately - divide and conquer until you reach a level of confidence in your "internals" that makes testing the "external" api efficient.

Comment: NiRR: consider a simple example:
I've a library with "sort" function. sort function uses lets say introsort algorithm which consists of a few functions/subsorts. I would not like to publicy them, but I'd like to test it. Should I have 5 or 6 libraries for this introsort?

Comment: TheOtherGuy: sorry, I'm not native, I just wrote it the way I thought it should be ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do 2) so you should be able to reorganize your file/folder/project like;

1) a static library project containing all the internal function and object 
2) a test project using any framework (there is a lot of framework with pro&con for each, my advice if you are beginner select the integrated solution or a simple framework). that test project must DEPEND (add dependcy in solution explorer menu) of the static lib. So you can add test on your internal implemtation

now the external api.

3) your old DLL project keep only the public API definition and implementation. And DEPEND of the static lib.

4) add a test project for your public api

No need to synchronize project and compile code twice, and with effort you could test more than just the external api without any internal code change.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, test-driven programming works well with many and small "units". Having a few and bloated "units" makes the *testing phase* untolerable!

The only viable solution I see is to isolate specific parts of the code and then step into them with the debugger. Having many `private` functions usually leads to the aforementioned issue and since you can't access them directly during *unit tests,* you should really consider using the debugger for the non-obvious.

Comment: You are right (about units). For me an unit is a class or function. Library is just a set of them. I'd like to test all classes. Most of them is hidden in library however. It's impossible (or at least ridiculous) to have a one library for one class.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak My answer was based on the assumption that you're not allowed to change the structure of the library. If you can, then go for it! If you can't then you'll have to start `stepping into` functions with your debugger, cheers!